# Where to find Java API Class diagrams?

Tags: java, class-diagram, class-hierarchy

Is there a site where we can find JAVA API class diagrams. 
It helps to be able to see the class hierarchy (example Exception class hierarchy) in a visual manner.
Thanks.

Comment: I doubt that you'll find it to be very useful.

Answer (score 3):

This might not be as visual as you like, but the hierarchy can be seen in [the official Java docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/overview-tree.html).

Answer (score 2):

If your are asking for class hierarchy in general, found this one on [Javase docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/)
[image]

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing pre-built that I know of. If you're using an IDE (Eclipse, NetBeans, Intelli-J, etc.) it almost certainly has a built-in class hierarchy browser.

That said, the online JavaDocs do have a text-based class hierarchy for every single class. As per your example, here's what it shows for [`Exception`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Exception.html):

[image: java.lang.Exception]

Answer (score 1):

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/overview-tree.html though it is not uml,but i think it is clear
althoug there is not api uml,we can look api tree

Answer (score 1):

i was looking for it too, i found this germany website [click here](http://www.falkhausen.de/en/diagram/html/java.util.Exceptions.html).

That site represents all class diagrams and also provided you 223 pdf files with those diagrams.

The problem is the java version (java 1.4) but it still very helpful to me.

Comment: Thanks! It now supports Java 8.

Answer (score 1):

I have recently started adding such Class diagrams along with the class lists based on search criteria on my blog. Here are few samples -

http://www.buggybread.com/2015/09/java-class-diagram-collections-classes.html

http://www.buggybread.com/2015/10/java-javaio-stream-classes.html

http://www.buggybread.com/2015/10/java-se-list-of-algorithm-classes-and.html

http://www.buggybread.com/2015/10/java-se-javalang-string-classes.html

http://www.buggybread.com/2015/10/class-diagram-java-se-javautil-map_2.html

I haven't added lot of such material for Java SE and it's still not linked and indexed properly. Still you can search either on website or on google by adding the site name to your search. Thanks.